# wpf create a style for a custom control

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I have a custom control that inherits from another (third party) control:

```
public class Int32EditBox : Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.IntegerUpDown { }
```

Then, I tried to create a style for this control:

```
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls;assembly=MyApp.Controls"
...     
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:Int32EditBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Controls:Int32EditBox}}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource DefaultDesignerContextMenu}" />
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
          </Style>
```

The problem is that I get an error that says the resource "MyApp.Control.Int32EditBox" cannot be found.

Does anybody know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: It appears that your target type is the same as your BasedOn type, which does not seem right to me.  The style will inherit any previously defined styles to that type - no need to base it on anything that I can tell.

Comment: I tried to omit the "BasedOn" stuff, but it looks like it's required. More than that. I have other styles for "default" wpf controls like following: `<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource DefaultDesignerContextMenu}" />
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
      </Style>` and it works

Comment: Have you overridden the DefaultStyleKey in your custom control?

Comment: No. Should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the static constructor of your custom control, otherwise it will use the style for Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.IntegerUpDown or whatever base class has set the default style key:

```
static Int32EditBox()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Int32EditBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Int32EditBox)));
}
```

And in order for the BasedOn to work, there must be another style with that key within the visual tree.